# SQL join get results that have no join aswell

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I checked many posts with related questions, but couldnt find an answer.

I have 2 tables which have a one to many relationship. One is customers and the other one is projects. One customer can have many projects. their PK and FK are customer.customer_id and project_customer_id.

Now when I use  the following SQL

```
SELECT *, COUNT(project.project_id) AS totalProjects 
FROM `customer`  LEFT JOIN `project` 
ON `project`.`customer_id` = `customer`.`customer_id`
ORDER BY `customer`.`date_created` DESC
```

However when I get all my customers now it only returns the customers which actually have a project. I used inner, outer, left, union and right joins but no luck. I also tried DISTINCT but didnt work either.

Does anyone have any idea for such a query that it returns all customers even if they have no projects?

thanks in advance,
Rodney

Comment: what are you expecting out of this query???

Comment: Your query looks correct. Can you post the tables structures, part of the data, it may help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are only concerned with the count of projects "if I understood correctly from your question", either create a function to get you this count, or write a sub query like the example below...

```
SELECT 
    *,
    (
       SELECT COUNT(project.project_id) from project
       WHERE
       project.customer_id = customer.customer_id
    ) AS totalProjects 
FROM
    customer
ORDER BY customer.date_created DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this query:

```
SELECT *, COUNT(project.project_id) AS totalProjects FROM `customer`  LEFT JOIN `project` ON `project`.`project_customer_id` = `customer`.`customer_id` GROUP BY `customer`.`customer_id` ORDER BY `customer`.`date_created` DESC
```

Answer (score -1):

Not clear from your question, but I think you are trying to list all `customers` and if there are any `projects` associated with a `customer` then list the number of 'projects'? If that's your question then the below should solve it for you:

`SELECT *, ISNULL((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Project WHERE CustomerID = C.CustomerID),0) AS ProjectCount 
FROM Customer C
ORDER BY C.Date_Created DESC`